# How to search for a file through Folders

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to search for a file in the whole memory with the ".png" extension.
My problem is that the SD card (or storage) contains many folders and I don't know how to reach to all of them.
Is there a way for me to scan the whole memory (SD card or storage) for the files that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to traverse the folders using the `java.io.File` API

You can call `File.listFiles(directory)`

Check out some examples here: [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_listfiles_filename_filter.htm)

Comment: its a very good example but it search in a specific folder,in want to search in the folders that inside the folders,do a whole drive scan.a in depth scan for files